# Runtime error using new AVFoundation classes in Swift project

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to use some new AVFoundation classes (e.g. AVAudioEngine, AVAudioFile) in a Swift project.

The following code compiles fine, but I get an error at runtime:

`let engine = AVAudioEngine()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
engine.attachNode(player)`

The runtime error:

`dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioEngine
  Referenced from: /Users/jamie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestAVAudioEngineSwift-btgetxkmjogozkbndstxrmmtnncb/Build/Products/Debug/TestAVAudioEngineSwift.app/Contents/MacOS/TestAVAudioEngineSwift
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
 in /Users/jamie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestAVAudioEngineSwift-btgetxkmjogozkbndstxrmmtnncb/Build/Products/Debug/TestAVAudioEngineSwift.app/Contents/MacOS/TestAVAudioEngineSwift`

The equivalent code in Objective-C compiles and runs fine.

It seems a bit odd that it's looking in `/System/Library/Frameworks` for the framework. I tried dragging the AVFoundation.framework from the Xcode6-beta application bundle into my project, but this didn't resolve the problem.

Am I doing anything wrong on the Swift side? Xcode config issue?

**EDIT: I am already importing AVFoundation with `import AVFoundation`**

Comment: try `import AVFoundation` or something similar?

Comment: @JackWu Yup, I'm already doing that, but this is a *linker* error not compiler error

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by upgrading to OS X 10.10, which contains an updated AVFoundation framework.

The fact that AVFoundation classes cause runtime error in Swift applications on OS X 10.9 is a bug and has been reported via the Apple bug reporter.